# Improper intergral

Tags: calculus

The improper integral $\int^\infty_1$$\frac{1}{x^2-2x+10}$ I am not sure how to tackle this problem, I know that this function doesn't have a vertical asymptote, the answer says the integral convergers and the area is $\frac{\pi}{6}$.  Secondly, I am not even sure what technique to use to integrate the function, any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $x^{2}-2x+10=(x-1)^{2}+9$, then $u=x-1.$

Comment: Of course! I had $(x^2 - 2x+9)+1$, I don't know what I was thinking, one of those days.

Answer (score 1):

In order to integrate rational functions in general, you're going to want to be comfortable with the case of a quadratic denominator.  A hint on how to simplify is to start by completing the square.